How to specify default font when converting html to pdf using Spire.doc for java library (Korean is broken)
I'm working on converting HTML to PDF.
Do you know how to specify a default font when converting html to pdf using the Spire.doc for Java library? (Korean is broken)
// html to pdf
public static void pdfConvertorDefault(String inputHtml) throws IOException {
    // pdf 파일 생성
    Document document = new Document();
    document.setCustomFontsFolders("D:\\font");
    Section section = document.addSection();
    section.getPageSetup().setPageSize(PageSize.A3);
    // Page 방향 (Landscape: 가로, Portrait : 세로)
    section.getPageSetup().setOrientation(PageOrientation.Landscape);

    String htmlText = readTextFromFile(inputHtml);  // inputHtml : "D:/test.html";
    
    document.setCustomFontsFolders("D:\\font"); // Font Folder 지정
    //add a paragraph and append html string.
    Paragraph p = section.addParagraph();
    p.appendHTML(htmlText); // PDF Convertor
   
    //Save to PDF
    document.saveToFile("D://SpireDoc_ouput.pdf", FileFormat.PDF);
}

// htmlFile To String
public static String readTextFromFile(String fileName) throws IOException{
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
    String content = null;
    while ((content = br.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(content);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}

